# FaceTime: An Error Occurred during activation

Tags: icloud, apple-id, facetime

Upon entering correct information into FaceTime on latest OS X, we receive "An error occurred during activation. Try again."

Have already tried resetting power controller and memory, making sure date and time are set correctly, etc.

Video here: 
https://vimeo.com/268399235

Comment: Have you followed all the troubleshooting steps in [this Apple Support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204408)?  Have someone else try to login with their Apple ID.  That will tell you if it's just your ID or a larger issue.

Comment: Yes, my apple ID works on the computer for example. Just not her apple ID.

Comment: If you don't get an error with your ID that means the system is setup ok.  Try looking at her Apple ID and verify it's working on other systems and in iCloud.com.

Comment: your apple id may be locked by facetime server. You should call Apple support. They will unlock your apple id.